# Printing a directiry tree

Tags: haskell

I want to make a code that takes a list of a directory tree, and print out the directory tree. See the exampel down. I am pretty new to Haskell, and wonder if any of you would give me some advices to how I can make this code.

```
data FileOrFolder = File Int | Folder [ FileOrFolder ]
prettyPrint :: FileOrFolder -> IO ()
```

If I put in the following input:

```
prettyPrint (Folder 4 [Folder 2 [File 5, Folder 3 [File 1, File 1, File 2] ], File 3, Folder [], 
File 4])
```

The output should be:

```
-Folder 4
    -Folder 2 
        -File 5
        -Folder 3
            -File 1
            -File 1
            -File 2
    -File 3 
    -Folder 0
    -File 4
```

Comment: Inside `prettyPrint` you can create helper function that will take one more argument expressing indentation, then just make it print stuff and if it gets folder as input it would execute everything inside it with increased indendation.

Comment: voting to close https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Directory structures are very well traversed with a recursive approach. If you look at the data type you will see that it is indeed a recursive data structure where one of the constructors, namely `Folder`, can take an arbitrary long argument of the data type itself.

Looking at the directory structure as a tree will help. Let's consider `File Int`s as leafs of the tree and `Folder [ FileOrFolder ]` as nodes which can have an arbitrary number (including 0) of leafs (Files) and/or other nodes (folders).

```
├── exercise.files
│   ├── identity.hs
│   ├── madness.hs
│   ├── maybe-another-monoid.hs
│   ├── optional-monoid.hs
│   └── trivial.hs
├── exercises.md
└── projects
    ├── empty_folder
    └── orphan-instance
        ├── Listy.hs
        └── ListyInstances.hs
```

This is a sample output of the `tree` command on linux. As you can see, the main indicator that a file/folder is inside another folder is how they are indented to the right. This indentation corresponds to the root to node/leaf path's length (also called depth or level of the node). As you dive down the recursive stack with your algorithm, you can keep track on how many levels you are down to echo that in your print of the file/folder.

Also, this is pre-order depth first search traversal, since you want to print out the parent folder before the children.